# Notion Api GET request Fail to pull data

Tags: google-sheets, notion-api

I'm trying to pull data from a notion database and only able to get 1st row. Anybody that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the right `page_size`
https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query